# How can a buildbot track new branches on Github?

Tags: git, github, buildbot

I've configured a buildbot (version 0.8.9) to track changes in all branches of a repository:

```
c['change_source'] = []
c['change_source'].append(GitPoller(
        "github.com:myaccount/myrepo",
        branches=True,
        pollinterval=300))
```

Works well except that it does not track the creation of new branches.
But it tracks changes made after the branch creation.
Example:

- a new branch is created and pushed to Github
- the buildbot does not track any changes
- a modification is made in that branch and pushed to Github
- the buildbot tracks that change and launch a build.

I'd like the buildbot to launch a build when a new branch is added in this repository.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it detect it if the new branch is created with changes? If you create a branch without commits there are no new commits in the repo so there's nothing to be detected

Comment: I don't think it detects anything (according to the log file). But new branches has at least one commit. These branches are created so a manager can review them before merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and am glad to find someone with the same problem -- tells me it's probably not my setup.

I dug into the issue a bit, and it turns out to be a bug in gitpoller.py. Fortunately, it's a relatively easy fix:

https://github.com/kuna-systems/buildbot/commit/97bf812e053a3dc68eed7c1bb291d584d6177663

After this modification, Buildbot immediately builds new pushed branches.

I have also filed a bug report with the project:

http://trac.buildbot.net/ticket/2841